# Is it possible to use template variables with Athena views, or must I use CTAS instead?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-athena, presto

I have the following situation:

1. One big `raw_data` table with raw data partitioned on YYYY/MM/DD. Each entry contains a unique ID and various other columns.
2. One smaller `anomalies` table with an anomaly score per data point, also partitioned on YYYY/MM/DD, Each scored entry contains the referenced unique ID.

I'm querying this data externally and so wanted to prepare a view that does something like:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW no_anomalies AS
    SELECT * FROM raw_data
    JOIN anomalies 
    ON raw_data.id = anomalies.referencedid
    WHERE isanomaly = false
```

and similarly another one where `isanomaly = true`. As it stands, I have to requery my entire data every time even if I only wanted a small subset (even `LIMIT 1` has to first execute the entire query above, obviously).

I was hoping that I would be able to add some templated filters in the view for this use case, i.e. something like:

```sql
    AND year BETWEEN ${year_start} AND ${year_end}
    AND month BETWEEN ${month_start} AND ${month_end}
    AND day BETWEEN ${day_start} AND ${day_end}
```

This makes more sense with a CTAS where I'm querying the new table, but that would require recreating the table or adding more data as new data comes in, which is an additional maintenance burden.

I've been combing the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/views.html) for a while now but I haven't come across anything that seemed like it would help.

Is using [CTAS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/ctas.html) and periodically recreating/adding new data the right way to go here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Amazon Athena does not support variables. You would need to include a `WHERE` statement in the query.

Comment: I see. So CTAS with periodic `INSERT INTO ... WHERE date = now` would be the way to go in such a case, correct?

Comment: I don't know enough about your use case to confirm either way.

Comment: Is there anything I can elaborate on past what's already in the description to help further the discussion, then?